# problem with session_start() throwing errors

Tags: php, session

I have a login form that sets a session cookie. It all worked fine for a long while until it started acting up this afternoon. As far as I know I only copied files to a different folder. So I've been playing around and finally went down to the very very basics.

My test file called `test.php` now has only 3 lines of code in it:

```
<?php
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) { session_start(); }
?>
```

When I run this file, an error_log is created with the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  session_start(): Session cannot be started after headers have already been sent in test.php on line 2
```

So as far as I can tell, it can't start the session because it already exists? I've closed my browser, rebooted, but still this error.

So then I created this file:

```
<?php
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
session_destroy();
session_start(); }
?>
```

But that gives me the error I expect:

```
PHP Warning:  session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session in test.php on line 3
PHP Warning:  session_start(): Session cannot be started after headers have already been sent in test.php on line 4
```

It can't destroy the session because it hasn't started yet, but then when I want to start it, I can't.

What am I doing wrong here?

I've been looking at answers on here but it seems the answers all point towards stuff being sent to the browser before the session_start() function is called, I don't see how that could be happening here as it is literally the only bit of code in my file.

Comment: `it can't start the session because it already exists?` no, it tells you that it cannot start session because headers already sent, probably because some html output already started somewhere

Comment: Any whitespace, or even non-printable characters that tagged along in a copy/paste, could be causing output.  If this is genuinely and literally all of the code you have then you may want to just create a new empty PHP file and re-type it, ensuring there is nothing before the opening `<?php` tag.

Comment: Make sure that if your test file is saved as UTF-8, it does not have a BOM. That could be considered output before your `<?php` opener, which can cause this problem.